# Service discovery says access-denied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, service-discovery

I am trying to query chaincode from nodejs sdk. But it throws an error

```
2019-01-18T12:21:05.586Z - error: [Channel.js]: Channel:secc.public received discovery error:access denied
2019-01-18T12:21:05.587Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: Channel:secc.public Discovery error:access denied
2019-01-18T12:21:05.845Z - error: [Channel.js]: Channel:secc.public received discovery error:access denied
2019-01-18T12:21:05.845Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: Channel:secc.public Discovery error:access denied
2019-01-18T12:21:05.845Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 2 Peers. Last error was Error: Failed to discover ::Error: Channel:secc.public Discovery error:access denied
```

When I try to use `discovery` from `cli` it says `access-denied` as shown below:

```
root@2f5f500732db:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# discover --configFile conf.yaml peers --channel secc.public  --server $CORE_PEER_ADDRESS
access denied
```

Comment: can you also attach the logs of the peers?

Comment: Did you by any chance solve this until now ?